# Meteor collection query 'undefined'

Tags: meteor

I have the code

```
datas = new Meteor.Collection("datas")
var data = datas.findOne('101abcde1f2345ac00000001')


if (Meteor.is_client) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        console.log(data.name)
    });
}
```

But what I get in the console is an `undefined` error. However if I type `console.log(data.name)` into the web inspector's javascript console (presumably after some kind of wait it works. I'm already putting the code in Meteor.startup to ensure that the DOM is ready. what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: where is the Restaurants Collection ? Restaurants = new Meteor.Collection('restaurants');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are using `autopublish` package. And (of course), `Meteor.startup` doesn't wait subscription completed.

Usually, we use **reactive context & data**  to do this in Meteor -

```
datas = new Meteor.Collection("datas")

if (Meteor.is_client){
  Meteor.autosubscribe(function(){
    var data = datas.findOne('101abcde1f2345ac00000001');
    if (data){ console.log( data.name )}
  });
}
```

Anytime `datas` collection has changes(?), the function in `Meteor.autosubscribe` will be called.

Comment: This does work but it gets called twice (once initially), and second when the datas collection is finally loaded up. Is there a way to only do it once? (ignoring changes-) because I have a .observe that only watches for when the particular document changes instead of any of the irrelevant ones

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But I don't think it's really neccesary. Maybe you can take a look at the `_markAsReactive` under Minimongo, and help yourself.