# How to dynamically change the background image in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm new to meteor and a bit struggling with the templating system.

I'd like to change the background-image property of the .body css class in meteor, according to the change in state of a variable in my db.

It's a leaderboard app (from the examples) with two players, when Joe's score is > 0, the background image should be joe.png, otherwise it's jack.png.

Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in the (isClient) block

```
Meteor.autorun(function() {
    if(Players.findOne({name:"Joe"}).score > 0) {
        $('body').css('background-image','url(/joe.png)');
    }
    else
    {
        $('body').css('background-image','url(/jack.png)');
    }
}
```

Basically Meteor.autorun will run the function when a reactive variable used inside it changes `Players` in this case. So when your players db changes, it will run this block of code.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip that got me on the right track, but I needed to add the "url()" in the second parameter of .css() :)

`$('body').css('background-image','url(/joe.png)');`

Comment: Aaaaand apparently it's `autosubscribe` you meant rather than `autorun`, because I stumbled on the same problem as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978663/meteor-collection-query-undefined), the object returned was "undefined". With `autosubscribe` it runs like a charm.

Comment: If thats causing you an issue it, place your `Meteor.subscribe` function in the `autosubscribe`. This `autorun` feature is meant for a slightly different use case to `autosubscribe`. The latter is for when the the client needs to change its subscription with reactive variables, while the first is only for a reactive change. You probably get undefined because the subscription isn't complete.

Comment: "place your Meteor.subscribe function in the autosubscribe." you mean in the `autorun` right? Yes I'm still struggling a bit with the concept of subscription, but by trial-and-error like this I'm starting to get it.

Comment: Keep the autorun as is, the reason it works with autosubscribe is it is also a reactive context, but if moving it there made it work the issue was probably one of subscription. So if you place your `Meteor.subscribe` in a `Meteor.autosubscribe` block it should fix the issue too. I learn't the concept of subscription quite well from www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-subscriptions-and-ddp it might also help clarify things

Comment: Of note is `Meteor.autosubscribe` has been depreciated from Meteor v0.55 in favour of putting the `Meteor.subscribe` in `Meteor.autorun`

Comment: Okay, I'll try to get it to work with the recommended syntax then. Thanks again for all !